# Unable to test Android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I cannot run a default-generated app from neither AVD or my Moto X. I don't have the developer edition, but I am in debug mode.

The AVD returns no error, however it loads the android bootlogo and stays there. I waited for a bit, no change.
Moto X V: 4.4.2

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trevor1134.liveleak"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.trevor1134.liveleak.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app is going to be a non-released app because I don't like the official LL app. :P

Comment: Can you post some screenshot, or more info?

Comment: Also if you can post the your manifest file and your phone OS version.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek There really is not way to post a screenshot, it doesn't show "can't connect to MotoX" it simply just doesn't detect my Moto X as a device for testing applications. And the emulator just doesn't progress past the android boot logo. I don't know how to add more detail with th situation I have.. No stacktrace.. No solution on google... If there is something I should look for to share I will gladly do so. Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the drivers for the Moto x? https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth

Comment: @ElectronicGeek I have, actually. I tried removing the default installed drivers and then using the installer, no joy.

Comment: Go to the adt-bundle platform-tools folder, shift-click and click the command prompt, then type in "adb devices" without quotes. Do you see any devices? Also, if you really need to, you can email yourself the apk, and then install it from there.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek I clicked adb.exe, is that what you mean? Because that iterates though text and then exits...

Comment: No, shift click on empty space, then type in "adb devices" in the command prompt window.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek It says list, has to echo's (empty space lines), and then exits...

Comment: That means that the adb drivers aren't set up. I would try uninstalling all drivers, then installing the motorola ones again.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek May you link me to a tutorial or elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: You don't really need a tutorial, go to Progam Files, uninstall the drivers, then reinstall from: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Intel Atom processor for 4.4.2. Make sure you update from android SDK.

[image]

Here your new setting for AVD.

[image]

DO NOT CHOOSE ARM because it more slower than Intel Atom. enjoy !

Comment: I ran it with it, and it went to the bootlogo, then stopped responding.

Comment: clean up your eclipse. ./eclipse -clean

Answer (score 0):

Install the ADB Drivers from: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

This will fix your problems, but if you need a tutorial, look here: http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/06/how-to-set-up-adb-usb-drivers-for-android-devices/